# How to close a Angular Modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ProjectSignedLoaUploadComponentComponent, {
            size: 'md', keyboard: true, backdrop: 'static'
        });
        (<ProjectSignedLoaUploadComponentComponent>modalRef.componentInstance).project = 
          this.project;
        (<ProjectSignedLoaUploadComponentComponent>modalRef.componentInstance).loaId = loaId;

        modalRef.result.then(result => {
            if (result) {
                this.reloadDatatable();
                
            }
        });
```

How to close this modal automatically when I click on Submit button or by clicking anywhere outside the modal?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your question

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component) to send data, and [the other documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component) about using it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

If you use MatDialogRef dialogRef, then dialogRef.close()